# Method links does not exist.

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

```
public function index()
    {
        $userbio = (Auth::user()->biometrics);
        if (Auth::user()->hasRole('User')) {
            $attendances = Attendance::latest()->orderBy('date')->paginate(30)->where('biometrics', '=', $userbio);
             return view('attendances.index',compact('attendances'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
        };
    }
```

Hi experts! I just wanted to ask why am i having an error of **Method links does not exist.** when i put "where('biometrics', '=', $userbio);". I am adding it so that the data it will show are only fields that are equal to $userbio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the where clause before the paginate call.

Try doing it this way:

```
$attendances = Attendance::latest()
    ->orderBy('date')
    ->where('biometrics', $userbio)
    ->paginate(30);
```